# SAML Response issue - Issuer of the Assertion not found or multiple

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml, identity, saml-2.0

I'm having issues generating correct Response from my custom IdP. When validating the generated response I get the following errors:

Issuer of the Assertion not found or multiple. A valid SubjectConfirmation was not found on this Response Found an invalid Signed Element. SAML Response rejected

```
<Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ID="_0a1fdd35-c51f-4516-89b8-c10a7a2be510" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-06-28T15:48:18.7007629Z" Destination="https://crnm.lessonly.com/auth/saml/callback">
 <saml:Issuer>https://crnmimis.etechhosting.ca/crnm_test/IDP/idplauncher.aspx</saml:Issuer>
 <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <SignedInfo>
     <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
     <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
     <Reference URI="#_327c4e68-b237-4fc0-8e10-7f3a1972ddd9">
        <Transforms>
           <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
           <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>AoAp4vUVc94YLEaOVfFT4kpLGvU=</DigestValue>
     </Reference>
  </SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue>e0RIeTieUbpfbIW4l3c4BQEPhoC1OvM8ghwF7R+Mpxa/1MedKxgL6HGFIbNbrELM9ouzntbRimphpxJOInRGOeMxhN2S369PlRhGr/52Pxs1HpRXOexqpjTu6DufdPmrLes+v2qScUh7/B+bAPvRi5tkw8yX2MviGPo2SQFGWSK9FZdn5SvpREnffAcj+uC8CJyFgaEk6Y2niNy4kQbp5XqEUVg7ve7x6dVAjMm26trTOopewyaiVyCW6iOW7M9tsWy5kbVcQkd/5aHie/9S4pt7ge5Bq1uEbs+DQ1YNlqKPeCLnEpvIC1tAnUEgJ1afaW6S8axgH/NGLcoChghxXm8=</SignatureValue>
  <KeyInfo>
     <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
     </X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
 </Signature>
<Status>
  <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
</Status>
<saml:Assertion Version="2.0" ID="_327c4e68-b237-4fc0-8e10-7f3a1972ddd9" IssueInstant="2017-06-28T15:48:18.7007629Z">
  <saml:Issuer>https://crnmimis.etechhosting.ca/crnm_test/IDP/idplauncher.aspx</saml:Issuer>
  <saml:Subject>
     <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">amilev1@visualantidote.com</saml:NameID>
     <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <saml:SubjectConfirmationData Recipient="https://crnm.lessonly.com/auth/saml/callback" NotOnOrAfter="2017-06-28T15:53:18.7007629Z" />
     </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
  </saml:Subject>
  <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2017-06-28T15:48:18.7007629Z" NotOnOrAfter="2017-06-28T15:53:18.7007629Z">
     <saml:AudienceRestriction>
        <saml:Audience>https://crnmimis.etechhosting.ca/crnm_test/IDP/idplauncher.aspx</saml:Audience>
     </saml:AudienceRestriction>
  </saml:Conditions>
  <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2017-06-28T15:48:18.7007629Z" SessionIndex="_327c4e68-b237-4fc0-8e10-7f3a1972ddd9">
     <saml:AuthnContext>
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
     </saml:AuthnContext>
  </saml:AuthnStatement>
  <saml:AttributeStatement>
     <saml:Attribute Name="UserID" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">125481</saml:AttributeValue>
     </saml:Attribute>
     <saml:Attribute Name="email" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">amilev1@visualantidote.com</saml:AttributeValue>
     </saml:Attribute>
     <saml:Attribute Name="first_name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">Angel1</saml:AttributeValue>
     </saml:Attribute>
     <saml:Attribute Name="last_name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">Milev1</saml:AttributeValue>
     </saml:Attribute>
     <saml:Attribute Name="name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">Angel1 Milev1</saml:AttributeValue>
     </saml:Attribute>
  </saml:AttributeStatement>
 </saml:Assertion>
</Response>
```

Comment: How do you validate it? do you get this message in you SAML SP?

Comment: The first error was due to incorrect xml. This tool helped me a lot: https://www.samltool.com/validate_xml.php I'm still working on the errors related to the signature. I think I'm doing everything right: Generate the response, load the assertion as XML document, sign it, then add the signature to the assertion.

Comment: Ok, from where are you getting that error message? is it from samltools?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delayed response but here is the resolution. The SAML browser addon I was using was modifying the output therefor the signature won't match. I changed the addon to another one and the problem disappeared.